# Hibernate search keeps trying to download wstx-asl-3.2.7.pom

Tags: hibernate, maven

Using Maven and Hibernate search I keep get the following info messages in my log:

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2//woodstox/wstx-asl/3.2.7/wstx-asl-3.2.7.pom

Answer (score -1):

that is ok, maven is downloading the dependency from dependencies in your pom. They may be transitive not directly what you've specified, if you don't want to download them just exclude them from your dependecies tag without actually deleting the dependency